# Скрипт горизонтального скроллинга страницы

Tags: jquery, html, прокрутка, css, javascript

Как сделать плавный, горизонтальный скроллинг страницы, как в Windows 8?

Как на этом сайте: http://impactweb.pl/themeforest/modernmetro-dark/

Answer (score 1):

То что Вы ищите называется Parralax Scrolling.

[В этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141687/) есть примеры, и варианты внизу статьи.
Горизонтально сделать скролинг - тоже что и вертикально, но только горизонтально. Это уже потуги CSS и разметки структуры страницы.

[А в другой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/169359/), на том же сайте, описано как сделать свой красивый скролл.

Answer (score 0):

На приведенном вами сайте используется плагин 
[CustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/). Вот [пример](http://ruseller.com/adds/adds1998/example/).